# I cannot run any java file that doesn't contain a specific string

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am seeing a weird issue: I have around 5 Test Cases that are written in java, and I am running these Test Cases using maven, but I cannot run any test cases (.java files) if the class name doesn't include the keyword "Test".

So, I am able to execute any class name that includes "Test" (e.g. LoginTest), but not any class name without "Test" (e.g. LoginModule).

Comment: Can you show the code of a class you can not run?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't odd behavior. It's a Maven convention. Test classes are identified by starting or ending the class name with the word "Test". As with any Maven convention, you can change it by [supplying configuration for the surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html), which is what runs the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys, this issue has been resolved after updating pom.xml file as below:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Page.java</include>
            <include>**/Page*.java</include>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
            <include>**/Test*.java</include>
         </includes>
      <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
       </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be easiest to just rename your test class.

Otherwise, with the surefire plugin, you can specify what test cases to include. By default, it has the following rules:

> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> `"**/Test*.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that start with "Test".
> `"**/*Test.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "Test".
> `"**/*TestCase.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "TestCase".

You can include a specific package if you'd like as well:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>**/package/*.java</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html